# Magnolia @cms.newBar

Tags: magnolia

I am creating some Magnolia templates and would like to know if any one has found a way to create a `@cms.newBar` and somehow use a node as the list of available paragraphs. The syntax is as below:

```
 [@cms.newBar newLabel="Add Content" paragraph="template1, template2" /]
```

I want to use the node instead to avoid having to come back and add new templates when they are created.

I have seen the docs [here](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/ref/4.0.3/magnolia-taglib-cms/tlddoc/cms/newBar.html) and know that nothing is specified but wanted to see if anyone had found a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do several things, all boiling down to the same:

- configure a string property containing "template1, template2", in your template definition. Assuming you're using Freemarker as the templating language, refer to it with `${def.thatProperty}` (def references your template definition)
- have your model class return that value: `${model.whatsCooking}`, where your model class has a method `String getWhatsCooking()` which returns "template1, template2" (or whatever else you could come up with that decides what paragraphs should be available
- [STK](http://stk.magnolia-cms.com) does something similar to (1) - its template definitions contains `List`s of "available" paragraphs, and its templates use some utility method to turn that into a comma-separated list, use with the new bar, so something like `${stk.toStringList(def.main.paragraphs)}` (I can't recall the exact names and semantics, but you get the gist).

You should perhaps consider looking into STK for that, and a whole lot of things.

As for documentation, perhaps [the templating guide](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/templates.html) and other docs will be more useful than the javadoc/tlddoc in this case.

HTH,